Create a new df column and assign value conditionally based on substring in another column
Beginner with pandas, so apologies if this seems trivial.
Trying to create a new column in a dataframe with each row's value dependent on whether a certain substring appears in a previous column, same row.
The code I'm using looks like this:
def function(x):
    if "a" or "b" or "c" in x:
        return "string"
    elif "d" or "e" or "f" in x:
        return "other string"
    else:
        return "default string"

df['new col'] = df['col'].apply(function)
print(df)


This successfully adds another column on the end of the dataframe, but every value in the column is "string". How do I prevent that?
In case it's useful context, df['col'].dtype spits out object.

Can you provide sample data to show what your input/ouput looks like?

You're running into the issue described here. The conditions of the form if "a" or "b" or "c" in x doesn't behave as you expect, and you need to replace them by something like if "a" in x or "b" in x or "c" in x.

@Seon that did the trick, helpful resource too. Thanks!

The issue is in how you are using the 'or' operator. I fixed your function:
def function(x):

    # Check if 'a', 'b', or 'c' is in the string x
    if "a" in x or "b" in x or "c" in x:
        return "string"

    # Check if 'd', 'e', or 'f' is in the string x
    elif "d" in x or "e" in x or "f" in x:
        return "other string"

    else:
        return "default string"

# Apply this function to each row of column 'col'
df['new col'] = df['col'].apply(function)
print(df)

Let me share more details on your initial condition
if "a" or "b" or "c" in x:

this checks:
("a" is not None) OR ("b" is not None) OR ("c" in x). 

("a" is not None) is always True, that's why it goes to the first if statement
